# Laptop is taking too long to startup and shutdown Samsung RV509 both windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, memory, shutdown

I have a Samsung RV509 Model Laptop and for the last three years it has worked perfectly. But for the last three months it has been really slow:

- Startup takes more than 20 minutes
- Shutdown takes more than 15 minutes

**Notes:**

1. I already formatted my OS C: drive and reinstalled the OS more than five times (I switched between Windows 7 and Windows 8 to check if something would change), but there have been no changes to the startup and shutdown duration.
2. I also tried to stop services during Startup  using `Msconfig`, which also did not solve my problem.
3. I had Quick Heal Antivirus Pro purchased version installed.

**Configuration:**

- Laptop model: Samsung RV509
- RAM: 6GB (4GB 1st slot + 2GB 2nd Slot)
- Hard disk: 500GB (5 drives, each drive having more than 50% free space)
- Processor: Intel5 (i5 Processor)

**Drivers installed:**

- Intel graphics driver
- LAN driver

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you getting any error while shutdown?

Comment: @vembutech no Errors While Shutdown but windows is not activated that might be the Issue?

Comment: @Kumar Is it a pirate copy? Why is it not activated?

Comment: @DavidPostill one month trial version is finished. also i don't have key

Comment: @Kumar Then you should buy a legitimate copy of Windows.

Comment: @DavidPostill  in trial period also it seems like that only.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Reboot-Cycle**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures the activity during shutdown and boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.I'll analyze why Windows boots and shutdows slow.

Comment: the Win10 SDK works for Win8. For Win7, use the 1511 SDK: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you verymuch, i will try this step and let you know.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i tried to install above mentioned exe file but taken too much time and Failed. Please let me know any other solution.

Comment: You can also try using Microsoft SysInternals Autoruns to disable other startup programs and services which will not show up in msconfig. If you posted a screenshot(s) of all the startup programs, we could help you determine which ones were not included with windows. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: what fails? post more details

Comment: if you don't tell me what fails when you use the WPT, I can't help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, *backup* anything important. You should have done it yesterday or a week ago, or pretty much any time before now. Its not too late. Back it up.

The fact that you reinstalled should mean the data's somewhere safe already, and that its likely not the OS. Drives do slow down with age, and the apparent lack of other issues makes me disinclined to assume its something else. I'd suggest not using a third party AV - defender/MSSE should be good enough, while you're troubleshooting, or even none at all (keeping the system off network while testing). Have as close to a clean install as possible

At this point, a good idea once you've backed up would be to check your drive's health. While these tools are in no way definitive, it would help you work out if your drives are at fault.

The *symptoms* indicate its a good time to replace your drive, assuming you can get the data out.  We'd also want to check the disks to be sure, but replacing the current boot disk is a good idea anyway.

There's two basic things to do here - checking to see how fast/consistent your drive is, and whether its reporting any errors.

Firstly its useful to rule out any obvious errors with the disk - My preferred tool here is [gsmartcontrol](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Downloads)

Double click on the attributes tab and look for anything highlighted

Run a short test. If it fails, your hard drive needs to retire. Then run the long test just to be sure (this takes several hours, so worth saving the time *if* its a dead drive)

I'd also look up the datasheet for your specific drive, and its data transfer speed, then run a tool like the free version of [hdtune](http://www.hdtune.com/download.html) or crystal disk mark (which I recommend the portable version of). You should be seeing speeds of up to 100-150mb/s peak, with a gentle curve down.  Drives do slow down with age, so if you're seeing very wierd,readings, you may need to change your drive too.

Comment: gsmartcontrol looked like such a nice catch that I tried it but was disappointed that it didn't  work with any of my hard drives. As far as I can see on sourceforge, last update was in 2012. Do you have a later version that I can download?

Comment: Works on all of mine. Any smart test tool would do the same. Standard's been about the same

Comment: Well, fails completely on my sata3 disks : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyVF4.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your boot and shutdown times are highly abnormal and must be caused by some problem. I see two possible explanations :

1. Software.
   As you have reinstalled Windows 5 times, it is unlikely that this is a
   software problem, that is - if the problem has occurred before installing any
   other software than Windows.
   However, if the problem only appears after third-party products are installed,
   find which one it is by reinstalling Windows again from scratch and adding
   other products one-by-one and rebooting.
2. Hardware.
   The only method for finding out hardware problems is replacing parts until
   the defective part is found. This method is more suitable for a repair-shop
   than for a private person of limited means (unlimited means = new computer).
   It might be worthwhile, before starting on that path, to find out as much
   information as possible.

One tool you can use is [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy).
Download and install the free version, then run it and look for information,
with special attention to the Storage section and on the S.M.A.R.T.
information of the disks and whether speccy is interpreting the disk status as "Good".

[image]

Another tool is the Microsoft Even Viewer.
For information on using this tool, see the how-to-geek article
[Using windows admin tools like a pro](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson3/).
Pay special attention to Errors :

[image: image2]

Comment: Thank you very much Friend :) , i am trying with what you suggested.

Comment: Any results to report?

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is with your hard disk , try installing a ssd (around 128gb) for the os drive , it will definitely fix your issue.

Comment: 128 GB? , how can install that much size of file ,my Hard disk  was separated 5 parts(101 GB- 4 Parts, 50GB-C drive).also i can,t download that much size file.

Comment: @Kumar what I meant was to replace your hard disk with a new Solid State Drive(SSD). That is not a program.  It is a type of hard drives